# how to add the font family in custom email newsletter?

Tags: html, newsletter

I am trying to make a custom email newsletter however in gmail I am not able to render the fonts that I want to render.So kindly let me know which code snippet shall I use for the same.

Comment: Just a comment: You might seriously want to reconsider importing an entire font for an email.

Comment: Issue is I am not able to render the fonts I need and its rendering different fonts specially in Gmail

Comment: I'm afraid that might be impossible: https://css-tricks.com/kinda-can-use-custom-fonts-html-emails/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any web fonts in email. Just be weary that they [aren't supported very well](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/font-face/).

That being said - some clients do support them!

To import fonts from a web font provider, you would add it in between your `<style>` tags like any other site.

Example (using google fonts [Open sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans?selection.family=Open%20Sans:300,400,600)):

```
<style>
...
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600');
...
</style>
```

And then when you use it in your email:

```
<td valign="top" align="center" style="font-family: Open sans, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size...">
   <span class="fallback_font">Your content here</span>
</td>
```

Now you may have noticed there is a span surrounding the content with the class `fallback_font`. This is for all the pesky outlooks (not 2002/3) [which don't support web fonts](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/font-face/). They require you to add a special class for them to have their own fallback. 
So again in the head place this block of code:

```
<!--[if mso]>
     <style type=”text/css”>
        .fallback_font {font-family: Arial, sans-serif;}
     </style>
<![endif]-->
```

This creates a conditional CSS rule which only microsoft outlooks will follow. This will force all outlooks to fallback to an Arial and/or sans-serif font. You will need to place this aroud EVERY instance where a webfont is used.

Hope this helps - any question feel free to ask :)